# Workaround for this?

Tags: java, architecture, wrapper

There are quite a few situations where I wished

```
this=somevalue
```

would be allowed in Java.
E.g. when I am in a superclass Person and I'd like to modify the type from Person to Customer a
an assignment like

```
this=new Customer();
```

would be helpful. Imagine that I have Customer Relationship System where I keep a list of Persons and I would like to handle them differently depending on their role but only one master role is allowed. So a Person can be a Customer or an Employee or a Friend or ...

All people start as Persons but at any time they could be "promoted" to a masterole. Later I might want to change the Masterrole.

Even with Factories, Dependendy injection and the like it still seems to be quite difficult to get a working solution without using a Role pattern.

What would be a good work-around to get the wanted effect that a reference to an object can be modified by the object itself? My first thought would be to have a Wrapper object that delegates all access to a "true object" - the true object fulfills the interface of the entity e.g. Person.
If I know want to move from Person to Customer the wrapper exchanges the "true" object. Are there any solutions along these lines?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this as we don't know *why* you'd want to do this. I can't say it's something I've ever wanted to do, so I don't know what problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: You cannot reassing `this`. What if you explained what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, your proposed [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) would be a clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want to achieve is not only changing the this pointer but all references to the instance. So the approach with the wrapper seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any solutions along these lines?

Yes. Your wrapper idea is a common and viable solution commonly referred to as the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). From [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns):

> In the State pattern, an object delegates requests to a State object
>   that represents its current state.